# Creating vertex in ArangoDB with batch mode

Tags: arangodb

Tried creating vertexes and edges with ArangoDB Java API without activating batch mode, all works well. However, when batch mode is enabled, it throws an unknown error when creating vertex. Below is the Java code, and the exception details.
Any idea why this is happening?
Thanks in advance!

## Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ArangoException {

    createNodesInBatch();

}
static public void createNodesInBatch() throws ArangoException {
    ArangoConfigure configure = new ArangoConfigure();
    configure.init();
    ArangoDriver arangoDriver = new ArangoDriver(configure);            

    arangoDriver.createDatabase("small_db"); 
    System.out.println("Database created.");
    arangoDriver.setDefaultDatabase("small_db"); 

    arangoDriver.createCollection("testEdgeCollection",
    new CollectionOptions().setType(CollectionType.EDGE));

    arangoDriver.createCollection("testVertexCollection",
        new CollectionOptions().setType(CollectionType.DOCUMENT));

    EdgeDefinitionEntity ed = new EdgeDefinitionEntity();
    // add edge collection name
    ed.setCollection("testEdgeCollection");

    // add vertex collection names
    ed.getFrom().add("testVertexCollection");

    // add vertex collection names
    ed.getTo().add("testVertexCollection");

    List<EdgeDefinitionEntity> edgeDefinitions = new ArrayList<EdgeDefinitionEntity>();
    edgeDefinitions.add(ed);


    arangoDriver.createGraph("testGraph", edgeDefinitions, null, false);
    System.out.println("Graph created.");

    arangoDriver.startBatchMode();;
    System.out.println("Batch mode started.");

    for (int nodeIdx = 0; nodeIdx < 10; nodeIdx++)
    {
        String nodeName = "node_" + nodeIdx;
        SimpleNode node = new SimpleNode(nodeName);
        VertexEntity<SimpleNode> vertex = arangoDriver.graphCreateVertex("testGraph", "vertextCollection", node, false);            
    }

    System.out.println("Batch execution started to create nodes");
    arangoDriver.executeBatch();

}
```

## Exception Message

Database created.

Graph created.

Batch mode started.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.createVertex(Unknown Source)
    at com.arangodb.ArangoDriver.graphCreateVertex(ArangoDriver.java:4570)
    at WhichDB.ArangoDBTest.App.createNodesInBatch(App.java:311)
    at WhichDB.ArangoDBTest.App.main(App.java:327)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.arangodb.http.InvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(InvocationHandlerImpl.java:38)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.arangodb.ArangoException: unknown error
    at com.arangodb.impl.InternalGraphDriverImpl.createVertex(InternalGraphDriverImpl.java:329)
    at com.arangodb.impl.InternalGraphDriverImpl.createVertex(InternalGraphDriverImpl.java:294)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: `VertexEntity<SimpleNode> vertex = arangoDriver.graphCreateVertex("testGraph", "vertex>>t<<<Collection", node, false);` If you remove that stray T, does that fix your exception?

Comment: Changed this line of code to: arangoDriver.graphCreateVertex("testGraph", "testVertexCollection", node, false);    Still see the same exception.

Comment: Can you retry the latest snapshot version?

Comment: Did the answer fullfill your needs? If not, whats missing? If, can you mark it accepted?

Answer (score 7):

There was an error in the ArangoDB Java driver. The problem in the driver was fixed in version 2.7.3.

I added your nice example code to [my tests](https://gist.github.com/a430ba1129ccfb0dc1ac31af4dd02d98) and tested it with ArangoDB 2.8.6.

Download the ArangoDB java driver on [github](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver) and compile it with maven:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -Dgpg.skip=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B
```

Maven creates the standalone driver JAR file (arangodb-java-driver-X.X.X-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar) containing all dependencies in the *target* directory.

Fetch the example code:

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/a430ba1129ccfb0dc1ac31af4dd02d98/raw/8db1033cacd9656f92b8c5b34f5fb1431df8730c/NodesInBatchExample.java
```

Compile the example code:

```
javac -classpath arangodb-java-driver-X.X.X-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar NodesInBatchExample.java
```

Start the ArangoDB without authentication on the default port and run the example code:

```
java -classpath arangodb-java-driver-X.X.X-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar:. NodesInBatchExample
```